# how to use sed to replace text in subfolders

Tags: ubuntu, sed

i use this code to replace some text in an HTML file:

```
sed -i 's/tttt/new-word/g' /home/zjm1126/*.html
```

This doesn't search for files in subfolders, though. How do I apply this command to subfolders?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
find /home/zjm1126/ -name '*.html' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/tttt/new-word/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try somthing like

```
for z in `find /home/zjm1126/ -type f -name "*.html"`; do
sed -e 's/tttt/new-word/g' $z>temp;
done
```